# Update MySQL with .html() in JQUERY/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some buttons people can click on and when they click on them it gets me what they clicked on as well as their comment. I usually just pass it on to another page with `$_GET` but I have a `textarea` on this one without a form. How can I use something like below to update a table:

```
function person_submit() {
    var Name = (".name").html();
    var Job = (".job").html();
    var PickComment = ("comment").val();
}
```

The mysql update statement is usually something like this in php

```
UPDATE table
SET name = ?, job = ?, comment = ?
```

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX to communicate with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ajax to resolve this issue :

```
var Name = (".name").html();
var Job = (".job").html();
var PickComment = ("comment").val();

$.ajax({
url: "test.php",
data : {
   name : Name,
   job : Job,
   pickComment : PickComment
 }
 }).done(function() {
   //Do something
 });
```

More informations [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it.